# Files in htdocs not showing up (MAMP) PHP

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I can't seem to find a concrete answer.  Within my htdocs folder, I created a folder named Testing.  Inside Testing, I placed to two php files named: email_form.php and email_script.php.

When I go on my browser(Chrome), I would type in localhost:8888/Testing in the search bar so that I could see it but I can't.  What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the server running? Have you tried http://localhost:8888/Testing/email_form.php?

Comment: Yeah it's running.

Comment: Yeah I tried that.  It's giving me a message saying "The requested URL /Testing/email_form.php was not found on this server."

Comment: Your server config may not allow you to view the files in a folder from the browser.

Comment: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/`?

Comment: Apple uses a non case sensitive file system default. Whyever, since it is against the unix philosophy. Could that be the issue here?

Comment: @pellepelle have you found a solution?

Comment: @Jose I was having this issue as well. Make sure you're putting the files in the correct mamp/htdocs folder. I didn't realize there were multiple mamp folders in my Applications directory.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found a solution. Keep in mind I am running on windows 10.
The default port was set to 80 and the url for the start page was just localhost/MAMP
I simply changed the default port in preferences to the usual 8888 and then typed localhost:8888/test/index.html to get my test page up and running. I know its an old thread but hopefully this helps someone

Answer (score -1):

If not one of the files is an index file, you need to add the file name in the URL. A common name for index file is index.php, but it depends on your configuration. In this case the file name in the URL is obsolete.

Additional be sure that php files are processed by your webserver.

While entering the filename in the url and the file is not shown (State 404), then check your config (vhost / virtualhost) settings if the correct document folder is used and if there is a name defined, so that the content will be delivered by using a dns name or maybe by a specific IP only.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The error message the OP cited clearly indicates that she/he directly tried to access a specific file.

Comment: I've literally tried everything, can't figure this out for the life of me.